# How to automate Entity Framework database migration within VSTS continuous integration

Tags: entity-framework, continuous-integration, azure-devops, entity-framework-migrations

I'm faced with this scenario: I want to release my software into production on Azure, but there's a code-first database migration that must be applied at the same time to an Azure SQL database. During the time that new software version is pushed without the new database schema (or vice-versa), there will be a period of time that software will throw the exception `The model backing the 'BlogContext' context has changed since the database was created.`.

My software is deployed upon pushing git commits to a branch using continuous integration in Visual Studio Team Services, so I really need a way to run `update-database` at the same time.

It appears this can be done using a manual publish from Visual Studio by checking the Update Database box (below), but I need this to be automated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the data just drop the dbo.__MigrationHistory table

Hope this helps.

Comment: I care vary much about the data. I elaborated slightly in my question. It's about the gap between database and software release.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take direct control over the deployment process (Team Services can help, or Octopus, Jenkins, others)? If so, deploy the database ahead of the code. That's how I would do it if I wasn't using Entity Framework. I would assume the same even with Entity Framework.

Comment: I wasn't given that requirement. Add that in, and we pause transactions or queue them during the deployment. There's a bunch of stuff we might have to do to work around this, yes.

Answer (score 0):

An entity framework context is initialised, by default, using `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>`. If the database schema is different than the EF model, then error `The model backing the 'BlogContext' context has changed since the database was created.` will be triggered.

By adding to your db context contructor `Database.SetInitializer<context>(null);` the model error will not be triggered. This means you can deploy schema changes to production, without causing model errors, ahead of the new version of the application being deployed that contains the new db context, which equals no down-time.

Make use of an appSetting so that production code will use the null initializer.